# find occurence of a set of words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a pattern with a small list of words that are illegal to use as nicknames set in a pattern variable like this:

```
$pattern = webmaster|admin|webadmin|sysadmin
```

Using `preg_match`, how can I achieve so that nicknames with these words are forbidden, but registering something like "`admin2`" or "`thesysadmin`" is allowed?

This is the expression I have so far:

```
preg_match('/^['.$pattern.']/i','admin');
```

// Should not be allowed

Note: Using a `\b` didn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about not using regex at all ? 

And working with [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) ?

For instance, this would do :

```
$pattern = 'webmaster|admin|webadmin|sysadmin';
$forbidden_words = explode('|', $pattern);
```

It explodes your pattern into an array, using | as separator.

And this :

```
$word = 'admin';
if (in_array($word, $forbidden_words)) {
    echo "<p>$word is not OK</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>$word is OK</p>";
}
```

will get you

```
admin is not OK
```

Whereas this *(same code ; only the word changes)* :

```
$word = 'admin2';
if (in_array($word, $forbidden_words)) {
    echo "<p>$word is not OK</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>$word is OK</p>";
}
```

will get you

```
admin2 is OK
```

This way, no need to worry about finding the right regex, to match full-words : it'll just match exact words ;-)

---

**Edit :** one problem might be that the comparison will be case-sensitive :-(

Working with everything in lowercase will help with that :

```
$pattern = strtolower('webmaster|admin|webadmin|sysadmin');  // just to be sure ;-)
$forbidden_words = explode('|', $pattern);

$word = 'aDMin';
if (in_array(strtolower($word), $forbidden_words)) {
    echo "<p>$word is not OK</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>$word is OK</p>";
}
```

Will get you :

```
aDMin is not OK
```

*(I saw the '`i`' flag in the regex only after posting my answer ; so, had to edit it)*

---

**Edit 2 :** and, if you really want to do it with a regex, you need to know that :

- `^` marks the beginning of the string
- and `$` marks the end of the string

So, something like this should do :

```
$pattern = 'webmaster|admin|webadmin|sysadmin';

$word = 'admin';
if (preg_match('#^(' . $pattern . ')$#i', $word)) {
    echo "<p>$word is not OK</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>$word is OK</p>";
}

$word = 'admin2';
if (preg_match('#^(' . $pattern . ')$#i', $word)) {
    echo "<p>$word is not OK</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>$word is OK</p>";
}
```

*Parentheses are probably not necessary, but I like using them, to isolate what I wanted.*

And, you'll get the same kind of output :

```
admin is not OK

admin2 is OK
```

You probably don't want to use `[` and `]` : they mean "any character that is between us", and not "the whole string that is between us".

And, as the reference : manual of the [preg syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) ;-)

Comment: Great potatoes! That's one informative reply, I'll check out the reg-exp you stated. The in array is of course a very valid suggestion to consider. Thanks again Martin!

Comment: As a sidenote: It's useful to use the strtolower on the nick as well, to control the control.

Comment: The parentheses *are* required. Without them, the anchors (`^` and `$`) would "stick" to the first and last word in the list, respectively. Alternation (`'|'`) has the lowest precedence of all regex operators.

Answer (score 0):

So, the forbidden words can be *part* of their username but not the whole thing?

In .NET, the pattern would be:

```
 Allowed = Not RegEx.Match("admin", "^(webmaster|admin|webadmin|sysadmin)$")
```

The "^" matches the beginning of the string, the "$" matches the end, so it's looking for an exact match on one of those words. I'm a bit fuzzy on the corresponding PHP syntax.